# Trigger at least one of each oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I am creating a trigger that guarantees me that there is at least one dancer of each sex. For example, if I have only 2 dancers on that table dancers, they will have one male and one female

I have these tables

```
dancers (artistic_name, sex, fnac, real_name)
couples (name1, name2, fnac, times_together)
```

The solution principle that I had was this trigger

```
create or replace trigger t_control
before insert or update on dancers
for each row
declare
    cnt number;
begin
    select count(*) into cnt
    from   dancers d
    where  :new.artistic_name != d.artistic_name
    and    :new.sex = d.sex;

    if cnt !=0 then
        raise_application_error('-20001', 'Not possible');
    end if;
end t_control;
/
```

But I have the problem that if I enter first feminine, then masculine, the rest of the inserts skips the trigger

How would you do for the expression "at least one of each"?

```
INSERT INTO dancers VALUES('artistic1', 'm', 'today', 'anna')    
INSERT INTO dancers VALUES('artistic2', 'f', 'today', 'paul')
```

From here, for each insertion the trigger jumps

```
ORA-20001: Not possible
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_TQJRRVAQQOICTXMWSHDG.T_CONTROL", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_TQJRRVAQQOICTXMWSHDG.T_CONTROL'

INSERT INTO dancers VALUES('artistic3', 'f', 'today', 'mery') 
INSERT INTO dancers VALUES('artistic4', 'm', 'today', 'joan')
```

Comment: Please post test data as text - not image - ant the expected result of that data.

Comment: What do you mean by one of each type?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai 
That for example to introduce instances, it has to be male or female. I give an example of what I have interpreted from the statement

Comment: So you can only have two dancers in total (two rows in the table)? Then make `sex` unique and constrain it to `M` or `F`.

Comment: Or, if you can have any number of dancers but you want to ensure that couples are mixed, then why are you writing a trigger on the `dancers` table? Perhaps the `couples` table should have column names like `name_female` and `name_male`  rather than `name1` and `name2`, then you could define some validation for each using a trigger or possibly foreign keys. (Using dancer IDs instead of names would also be a good idea.)

Comment: I have to ensure that there is at least one of each sex on the dancer table

Comment: So you can’t insert the first row unless it’s part of a multi-row insert (`insert ... select ... from` or `insert all`), or the trigger explicitly checks whether there is only one row and allows it regardless. That seems unreasonable. Does that mean the last dancer of each sex can’t leave your dance school? Surely it would make more sense to validate couples.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is checking that there are no other dancers of the same sex that the one you're inserting. So when you insert the third dancer, you get the error. I think that's not what you're trying to do: Insure that there is at least one dancer of each sex. So, your trigger should:

1. check that this is not the first row in the table
2. if there are other rows, at least one should be of different sex
3. It should check for 'delete' DMLs, so when you delete a dancer, you must insure that there are other dancers of the same sex.
   Is this in fact what you're trying to do?